# Is there any way to backup specific branch with history?

Tags: git

I want to backup only one branch with history.

I don't want to push it to remote, I only want to do this in the local computer.

I've tried GitLab download, although you can get that branch code, there is no history.

Right now, I've got only one way to do it, that is

1. Copy whole directory to other places
2. remove every other branch

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: having files in multiple places is the definition of a backup, using git is a good choice, one could code a commit hook to copy files into a diff git repo (and even commit)

Comment: A remote doesn’t need to be online, you can have a remote on the local machine.

Comment: To elaborate on @evolutionxbox answer: create a new local bare repository, push the branch into it and backup the bare repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `--single-branch` option.

For example, a remote clone:

```
git clone https://mygitsource.com/seumasmac/myproject -b cool-branch --single-branch
```

Or, from a local folder:

```
git clone myproject/ myproject-cool-branch/ -b cool-branch --single-branch
```

And that's it!